# InkCanvas Load/Save operations

Tags: c#, wpf, file, bitmap, inkcanvas

I've never used `InkCanvas` control before. What I need is to load up a file into `InkCanvas`, draw some scribbles and get ther resulting image. And I want to make some additional operations with gotten image.

### As for saving

Correct me if I'm wrong. I've found a link: http://www.centrolutions.com/Blog/post/2008/12/09/Convert-WPF-InkCanvas-to-Bitmap.aspx 
According to the post will be loaded image considered in addition to user scribbles. Or it only converts scribbles to bitmap?

### As for loading

How do I load image using OpenFileDialog? I don't want to use ISF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Saving:**

If you want to be able to manipulate strokes after saving, then you need to save the strokes. You can do this by using the [StrokeCollection.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590544%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.

```
var fs = new FileStream(inkFileName, FileMode.Create);
inkCanvas1.Strokes.Save(fs);
```

You can then load this again and have the individual strokes accessible. However, once you render it out (e.g. to a bitmap) then that rendered file can only be loaded as a Bitmap and not individual strokes. (Of course, you can do both and save the strokes as a separate file). To save as a bitmap, you can use the code in the link you posted to.

**Loading**

Loading a bitmap to an Image control is straightforward since the `OpenFileDialog` will return the image path.

```
if (myOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    myImageControl.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(myOpenFileDialog.FileName, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

That will load the image and display it in an image control on your form.

Edit: 
I don't think you can load a bitmap straight to an InkCanvas. However, you can load the strokes instead.

To load the strokes again, you can use [StrokeCollection(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522846.aspx)

```
var fs = new FileStream(inkFileName,
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StrokeCollection strokes = new StrokeCollection(fs);
inkCanvas1.Strokes = strokes;
```

For more functions, you can read this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Ink1.aspx).

Comment: 1) Will code from the post above store both user's scribbles and background image as one image?

Comment: 2) What do you mean when writing `MyImageControl`. I need to upload image into `InkCanvas`. I've found no such a property?

Comment: 1) No. The users scribbles (`Strokes`) are stored in a separate file. 2) I don't think InkCanvas can load bitmaps. Instead, you can load the strokes again using StrokeCollection(Stream) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522846.aspx (I've updated the answer)

Comment: But I read it is quite overkill reading/writing strokes. And I need to get pixels from resulting image. It means I need not separate result but combined(modified image).

Comment: If you want to analyse pixels, then `InkCanvas` is not the best control to use to do that. Once you've created the image in InkCanvas, you can save a bitmap (from the link you gave) and convert the byte array to a `Bitmap` control. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwdz9wf7.aspx) To convert: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e57f7731-c703-4c17-b1a2-32b155f9b745/  You can then use the Bitmap.GetPixel method to get the pixels or, if you need efficiency, use this method: http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm

Comment: I know how to analyse. I don't know how to upload image into `InkCanvas`. I decided to use this kind of control cause it really reduces painting handling.